# version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found

Tags: apt, samba

Hello ubuntu community :)

I've recently started getting an error when installing stuff with apt-get which I can't seem to get rid of. Here are the error logs:

Initial Error when installing anything with apt-get:

```
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Checking smb.conf with testparm
testparm: error while loading shared libraries: libaesni-intel.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package samba-common-bin (--configure):
 installed samba-common-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                      dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba:
 samba depends on samba-common-bin (= 2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1); however:
  Package samba-common-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of winbind:
 winbind depends on samba-common-bin (= 2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1); however:
  Package samba-common-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package winbind (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba-common-bin
 samba
 winbind
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
 ❯❯❯ sudo dpkg --configure samba-common-bin
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Checking smb.conf with testparm
testparm: error while loading shared libraries: libaesni-intel.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package samba-common-bin (--configure):
 installed samba-common-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba-common-bin
```

```
❯❯❯ locate libaesni-intel.so.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libaesni-intel.so.0
```

Upon trying to run testparm (which seems to be a problem)

```
❯❯❯ ldd /usr/bin/testparm
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtime-basic.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtalloc-report.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgenrand.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libCHARSET3.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsocket-blocking.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-setid.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libserver-role.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmbd-shim.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtdb-wrap.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsys-rw.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmessages-util.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libinterfaces.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libiov-buf.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmb-transport.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libserver-id-db.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmessages-dgm.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-reg.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libdbwrap.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-tdb.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba3-util.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-sockets.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcli-smb-common.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtime-basic.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsys-rw.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgenrand.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsocket-blocking.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-hostconfig.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libserver-role.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-hostconfig.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-hostconfig.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtime-basic.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtevent-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgenrand.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-standard.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-standard.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-nbt.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-nbt.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libwinbind-client.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libauthkrb5.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgenrand.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcliauth.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamdb-common.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libldbsamba.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcli-ldap-common.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libkrb5samba.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgenrand.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamdb-common.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libdbwrap.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libldbsamba.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcliauth.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-tdb.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libauthkrb5.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libkrb5samba.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/testparm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-krb5pac.so.0)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc475f3000)
    libpopt-samba3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libpopt-samba3.so.0 (0x00007f5634332000)
    libsmbconf.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0 (0x00007f5634251000)
    libsamba-util.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0 (0x00007f56341d9000)
    libsamba-debug.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0 (0x00007f56341ce000)
    libsamba-sockets.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-sockets.so.0 (0x00007f56341b3000)
    libsamba-hostconfig.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-hostconfig.so.0 (0x00007f5634185000)
    libserver-role.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libserver-role.so.0 (0x00007f563417e000)
    libtalloc.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtalloc.so.2 (0x00007f563416c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5634149000)
    libpopt.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpopt.so.0 (0x00007f563413b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5633f49000)
    libsamba-security.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0 (0x00007f5633f27000)
    libiov-buf.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libiov-buf.so.0 (0x00007f5633f20000)
    libCHARSET3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libCHARSET3.so.0 (0x00007f5633f1b000)
    libcli-smb-common.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcli-smb-common.so.0 (0x00007f5633ee8000)
    libsmbd-shim.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmbd-shim.so.0 (0x00007f5633ee3000)
    libsamba-errors.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-errors.so.1 (0x00007f5633d98000)
    libsocket-blocking.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsocket-blocking.so.0 (0x00007f5633d93000)
    libtevent-util.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtevent-util.so.0 (0x00007f5633d8a000)
    libsys-rw.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsys-rw.so.0 (0x00007f5633d85000)
    libndr.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr.so.0 (0x00007f5633d6c000)
    libdbwrap.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libdbwrap.so.0 (0x00007f5633d5e000)
    libsamba3-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba3-util.so.0 (0x00007f5633d51000)
    libutil-reg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-reg.so.0 (0x00007f5633d4c000)
    libmessages-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmessages-util.so.0 (0x00007f5633d45000)
    libutil-tdb.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-tdb.so.0 (0x00007f5633d40000)
    libinterfaces.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libinterfaces.so.0 (0x00007f5633d3b000)
    libmessages-dgm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmessages-dgm.so.0 (0x00007f5633d2d000)
    libtalloc-report.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtalloc-report.so.0 (0x00007f5633d28000)
    libserver-id-db.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libserver-id-db.so.0 (0x00007f5633d23000)
    libreplace.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0 (0x00007f5633d1c000)
    libsmb-transport.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmb-transport.so.0 (0x00007f5633d14000)
    libtdb-wrap.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtdb-wrap.so.0 (0x00007f5633d0f000)
    libgenrand.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgenrand.so.0 (0x00007f5633d0a000)
    libutil-setid.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-setid.so.0 (0x00007f5633d05000)
    libtime-basic.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtime-basic.so.0 (0x00007f5633d00000)
    libndr-standard.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-standard.so.0 (0x00007f56339f9000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f56339dc000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f56339c0000)
    libtevent.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtevent.so.0 (0x00007f56339ab000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f56339a2000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f5633988000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f5633975000)
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f563391f000)
    libtdb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtdb.so.1 (0x00007f5633905000)
    libaesni-intel.so.0 => not found
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f5633856000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f563384e000)
    libndr-nbt.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-nbt.so.0 (0x00007f5633827000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5634345000)
    libndr.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr.so.1 (0x00007f563380a000)
    libgensec.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgensec.so.0 (0x00007f56337d7000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f5633601000)
    libmsghdr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmsghdr.so.0 (0x00007f56335fa000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f56335de000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f56335c1000)
    libgssapi.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3 (0x00007f563357c000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f563356f000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f5633546000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f5633525000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f5633407000)
    libgssapi-samba4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgssapi-samba4.so.2 (0x00007f56333d1000)
    libasn1util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libasn1util.so.0 (0x00007f56333c6000)
    libwbclient.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwbclient.so.0 (0x00007f56333b5000)
    libndr-samba.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libndr-samba.so.0 (0x00007f563325e000)
    libsamdb.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0 (0x00007f5633242000)
    libsamba-modules.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-modules.so.0 (0x00007f563323d000)
    libsamba-credentials.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0 (0x00007f5633227000)
    libcom_err-samba4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcom_err-samba4.so.0 (0x00007f5633220000)
    libauthkrb5.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libauthkrb5.so.0 (0x00007f5633205000)
    libcliauth.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcliauth.so.0 (0x00007f56331ed000)
    libkrb5samba.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libkrb5samba.so.0 (0x00007f56331dd000)
    libcommon-auth.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcommon-auth.so.0 (0x00007f56331ce000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f5633096000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f5633075000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f5632ef3000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f5632edd000)
    libnettle.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7 (0x00007f5632ea3000)
    libhogweed.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.5 (0x00007f5632e6c000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f5632de6000)
    libheimntlm.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0 (0x00007f5632dda000)
    libkrb5.so.26 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26 (0x00007f5632d47000)
    libasn1.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8 (0x00007f5632ca0000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f5632c99000)
    libhcrypto.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4 (0x00007f5632c61000)
    libroken.so.18 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18 (0x00007f5632c46000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f5632c23000)
    libkrb5-samba4.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libkrb5-samba4.so.26 (0x00007f5632bb1000)
    libasn1-samba4.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libasn1-samba4.so.8 (0x00007f5632b32000)
    libhcrypto-samba4.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libhcrypto-samba4.so.5 (0x00007f5632afb000)
    libroken-samba4.so.19 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libroken-samba4.so.19 (0x00007f5632aea000)
    libheimbase-samba4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libheimbase-samba4.so.1 (0x00007f5632ae4000)
    libwinbind-client.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libwinbind-client.so.0 (0x00007f5632ade000)
    libldbsamba.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libldbsamba.so.0 (0x00007f5632aaf000)
    libsamdb-common.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamdb-common.so.0 (0x00007f5632a7d000)
    libcli-ldap-common.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcli-ldap-common.so.0 (0x00007f5632a71000)
    libldb.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldb.so.2 (0x00007f5632a3c000)
    libndr-krb5pac.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-krb5pac.so.0 (0x00007f5632a2d000)
    libMESSAGING-SEND.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libMESSAGING-SEND.so.0 (0x00007f5632a28000)
    libjansson.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjansson.so.4 (0x00007f5632a17000)
    libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f5632a0b000)
    libwind.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0 (0x00007f56329e1000)
    libheimbase.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1 (0x00007f56329cf000)
    libhx509.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5 (0x00007f5632981000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f5632856000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f563281b000)
    libhx509-samba4.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libhx509-samba4.so.5 (0x00007f56327d0000)
    libwind-samba4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libwind-samba4.so.0 (0x00007f56327a6000)
    libflag-mapping.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libflag-mapping.so.0 (0x00007f563279f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5632650000)
```

Essentially, there appears to be a missing samba library which causes `testparm` to fail to run. However upon running locate, I am able to find the library in the samba library folder. I even tried to patchelf to reattach the library but to no avail.

Following up with the error, I ran `ldd` to list dynamic libraries linked with samba and noticed that there were many libraries which threw an error saying `version 'SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found`.

I am out of ideas on how I could fix this issue. Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead.

Comment: @24601 Thank you very much! That was a neat fix :) Didn't think reinstalling was the solution.

Comment: @muru I apologize for the screenshots. I will take note in the future :)