# SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU not found

Tags: 20.04, gnome, samba

I've recently opened a thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376059/version-samba-4-11-6-ubuntu-not-found) with an identical title which suggested to me that I purge my samba and reinstall it based on an older question posted in this forum.

I thought everything was fixed when I purged samba as I no longer had apt-get errors, however, I realized that the problem still persist when I just realized that my `gnome-control-center` is using broken SAMBA libraries.

```
   ~ ❯❯❯ gnome-control-center 
gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries: libaesni-intel.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

   ~ ❯❯❯ ldd /usr/bin/gnome-control-center
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba3-util.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmsrpc3.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-cmdline.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgse.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libdcerpc-samba.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsecrets3.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/liblibcli-lsa3.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcli-smb-common.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/liblibsmb.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgenrand.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtime-basic.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtalloc-report.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgenrand.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libCHARSET3.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsocket-blocking.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-setid.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libserver-role.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmbd-shim.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtdb-wrap.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsys-rw.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmessages-util.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libinterfaces.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libiov-buf.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmb-transport.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libserver-id-db.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmessages-dgm.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-reg.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libdbwrap.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-tdb.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba3-util.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-sockets.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcli-smb-common.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtime-basic.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsys-rw.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgenrand.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsocket-blocking.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtime-basic.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtevent-util.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-standard.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-standard.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgenrand.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamdb-common.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libdbwrap.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libldbsamba.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcliauth.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-tdb.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libauthkrb5.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libkrb5samba.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-hostconfig.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libserver-role.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-hostconfig.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-hostconfig.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdcerpc-binding.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgensec.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdcerpc-binding.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdcerpc-binding.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-sockets.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdcerpc-binding.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-nbt.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-nbt.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libwinbind-client.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwbclient.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libauthkrb5.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgenrand.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcliauth.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamdb-common.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libldbsamba.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcli-ldap-common.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libkrb5samba.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0)
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0: version `SAMBA_4.11.6_UBUNTU' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-krb5pac.so.0)
    ...
    libaesni-intel.so.0 => not found
    ...
```

Delving deeper into the problem, I noticed that even after purging samba, the libraries still remain at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba` and are used by other programs.

I have reinstalled samba, samba-common-bin and samba-libs, but it does not solve anything.

Now my question is how can I fix this issue without breaking things more?

Why is libaesni-intel.so.0 undetected?

```
   ~ ❯❯❯ uname -a
Linux user 5.11.0-38-generic #42~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 28 20:41:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: based on the linked answer in your previous question, did you re-install samba as suggested? https://askubuntu.com/a/225802/307670 Your new question is silent on this point.

Comment: @24601 Yes I did re-install samba as suggested. Sorry for the lack of clarification. I've purged and reinstalled samba samba-common-bin and samba-common. I've also reinstalled (without purging as I'm afraid it may break stuff) samba-libs and it still does not solve anything. What I suspect is that libaesni-intel.so.0 being undetected is the main problem here that causes samba to break and hence the libraries to be unfunctional.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reinstall the [package which provides missed *libaesni-intel.so.0*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libaesni-intel.so&searchon=contents)  library by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libwbclient0
```

and then retry launching `gnome-control-center`.

Comment: thanks! This solution solves my problem and now I can open gnome control center after reinstall the library.